# LSTM for predicting characters: cell state and hidden state in the training loop

Tags: pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

My goal is to build a model that predicts next character.
I have built a model and here is my training loop:

```
model = Model(input_size = 30,hidden_size = 256,output_size = len(dataset.vocab))

EPOCH = 10
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
init_states = None

for epoch in range(EPOCH):
    loss_overall = 0.0
    
    for i, (inputs,targets) in enumerate(dataloader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        pred = model.forward(inputs) 
        loss = criterion(pred, targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

As you can see I return only predictions of the model, but not `cell_state` and `hidden_state`.
So alternative is : `pred,cell_state,hidden_state = model.forward(inputs)`

My question is: should I do it for the prediction of characters task? Why/why not?
And in general: when should I return my hidden and cell state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand hidden states, here's a excellent diagram by [@nnnmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1726797/nnnmmm) from [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302810/whats-the-difference-between-hidden-and-output-in-pytorch-lstm).

[image]

The hidden states are `(h_n, c_n)` i.e. the hidden states at the last timestep. Notice how you can't access the previous states for timesteps `< t` and all hidden layers. Retrieving those *final* hidden states would be useful if you need to access hidden states for a bigger RNN comprised of multiple hidden layers. However, usually you would just use a single `nn.LSTM` module and set its `num_layers` to the desired value.

You don't need to use hidden states. If you want to read more about [this thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/example-of-many-to-one-lstm/1728/4) from the PyTorch forum.

---

Back to your other question, let's take this model as an example

```
rnn = nn.LSTM(input_size=10, hidden_size=256, num_layers=2, batch_first=True)
```

This means an input sequence has `seq_length` elements of size `input_size`. Considering the batch on the first dimension, its shape turns out to be `(batch, seq_len, input_size)`.

```
out, (h, c) = rnn(x)
```

If you are looking to build a character prediction model I see two options.

- You could evaluate a loss at every timestep. Consider an input sequence `x` and it's target `y` and the RNN output `out`. This means for every timestep `t` you will compute loss(out[t], y[t])`. And the total loss on this input sequence would be averaged over all timesteps.
- Else just consider the prediction on the last timestep and compute the loss: `loss(out[-1], y)` where `y` is the target which only contains the *`seq_length+1`-th* character of the sequence.

If you're using `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`, both approaches will only require a single function call, as explained in your [last thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65470212/valueerror-expected-target-size-128-44-got-torch-size128-100-lstm-pyt).